# Declaration for an UIImage in NSObject

Tags: ios

[image]

Reffered these links 
[Adding an image to a NSObject - Possible?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15106683/adding-an-image-to-a-nsobject-possible)
[How to save to and read from a NSObject](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17244823/how-to-save-to-and-read-from-a-nsobject)

Answer (score 1):

All UI related classes are defined in the UIKit framework. You need to import `UIKit` in the `RSObject.h` header file, in-order to use them all.

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
```

Answer (score 0):

NSObject is the root class of most Objective-C class hierarchies. Through NSObject, objects inherit a basic interface to the runtime system and the ability to behave as Objective-C objects.

But the UIKit framework  provides the crucial infrastructure needed to construct and manage iOS apps.
UIKit framework provides support for user-interface content. Hence in order to use object of UIImage in NSObject you need to import UIKit in your class which has NSObject as base class.

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
```

Refer [AppleDocumentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIImage_Class/).